# Converting JSON object into PHP array

Tags: javascript, json, tostring

I am trying to convert a JSON object into a PHP array for my PHP script but I keep getting an error message that json_decode expects 1 parameter to be a string but array given. I have tried to serialize, tringify and json_encode the script but nothing works. My script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[id=ajax]').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  //var form_data = $(this).serialize()
  var form_data = { 
      submit: $('input[name=submit]').val(),
      id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
      name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
      price: $('input[name=price]').val(),
      quantity: $('input[name=quantity]').val()
      };

  var json = json_encode(form_data);
    //console.log($json)
  $.ajax({
      url : 'test.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data : json
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ... That's javascript not PHP...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong you need to add JSON.stringify rather you are adding **`json_encode`** which is a php function for encoding an array to JSON string ad you are sending JSON object rather JSON string to your php script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[id=ajax]').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  //var form_data = $(this).serialize()
  var form_data = { 
      submit: $('input[name=submit]').val(),
      id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
      name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
      price: $('input[name=price]').val(),
      quantity: $('input[name=quantity]').val()
      };

  var json = JSON.stringify(form_data);
    //console.log($json)
  $.ajax({
      url : 'test.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data : json
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

for further read [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: I have tried to use JSON.stringify but this is outputted - array(0) { }

Comment: check with console output for your json object

Comment: I can see the string in the console, and thank you for the code. I have given the answer a green tick. Do you know how I would convert that into a PHP array?

Comment: you need to use json_deocde over receiving that string in PHP file.

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($_POST, true)); This is what I get - Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 4
NULL

Comment: first, do var_dump on just $_POST and then get a JSON string from there and perform decode operation on that one,

Comment: var_dump ($_POST) gives me - array(0) { }

Comment: Change data:json to data:{json:json} in your javascript code and you will get that data

Comment: I have changed data:json, to data:{json:json} but still get array(0) { }